# How to display Tweets of a particular user in an Android app

Tags: android, twitter

I have a twitter account. I also have an android app. If I want to obtain my most recent tweets, say 15, do I still have to add my application to the dev.twitter page and obtain the two Twitter keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the source code from here ([Display Tweets of a particular user in an Android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/01/30/display-tweets-of-a-particular-user-in-an-android/))

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/rl_menu"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Twitter Tweets"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_menu"></ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.gettweets;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to use a twitter application keys to access a user's timeline
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   final static String ScreenName = "Deepshikhapuri";
   final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
   ListView lv_list;
   ArrayList<String> al_text = new ArrayList<>();
   Adapter obj_adapter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      lv_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_list);

      downloadTweets();
   }

   // download twitter timeline after first checking to see if there is a network connection
   public void downloadTweets() {
      ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

      if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
         new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
      } else {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please check your internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }

   // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
   private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "nW88XLuFSI9DEfHOX2tpleHbR";
      final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "hCg3QClZ1iLR13D3IeMvebESKmakIelp4vwFUICuj6HAfNNCer";
      final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
      final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";
      final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         dialog.setTitle("Loading");
         dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
         dialog.show();

      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
         String result = null;

         if (screenNames.length > 0) {
            result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
         }
         return result;
      }

      // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Log.e("result",result);
         dialog.dismiss();

         try {
            JSONArray jsonArray_data = new JSONArray(result);
            al_text.clear();
            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray_data.length();i++){

               JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_data.getJSONObject(i);
               al_text.add(jsonObject.getString("text"));

            }
         }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }



         // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
         obj_adapter= new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), al_text);
         lv_list.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
      }


      // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
      private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
         Authenticated auth = null;
         if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
            try {
               Gson gson = new Gson();
               auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
               // just eat the exception
            }
         }
         return auth;
      }

      private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            if (statusCode == 200) {

               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

               BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
               String line = null;
               while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line);
               }
            } else {
               sb.append(reason);
            }
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
         } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
         } catch (IOException ex2) {
         }
         return sb.toString();
      }

      private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
         String results = null;

         // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
         try {
            // URL encode the consumer key and secret
            String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
            String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

            // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
            // encoded consumer secret
            String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

            // Base64 encode the string
            String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
            String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
            Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

            // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
            // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
            if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

               // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
               HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName);

               // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
               // header with the value of Bearer <>
               httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
               httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
               // update the results with the body of the response
               results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
            }
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
         } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
         }
         return results;
      }
   }
}
```

**Authenticated.java**

```
package com.gettweets;

public class Authenticated {
   String token_type;
   String access_token;
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
package com.gettweets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;



public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<String> al_newslist=new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(Context context,   ArrayList<String> al_newslist) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_layout, al_newslist);
        this.al_newslist=al_newslist;
        this.context=context;



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE",al_newslist.size()+"");
        return al_newslist.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_newslist.size() > 0) {
            return al_newslist.size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);



            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


       viewHolder.tv_name.setText(al_newslist.get(position));


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_name;



    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are a lifesaver

Comment: is there any code get tweets with particular hashtag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following GET method for this, with the screen name parameter and count. Also according to the document you need authorization also.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json
```

For more information  read here [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/statuses)